# Integrate freshchat with my ionic 3 application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, freshdesk

I want to integrate FreshChat with my Ionic 3 application. FreshChat currently doesn't have any support for cordova. Is there any way i can use FreshChat web messenger. I tried importing the script in my index.html and tried to access the window.fcSettings but it was of no use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

window.fcSettings is intended for async load. Please use the snippet below.

```
if (window.fcWidget) {
   window.fcWidget.init(payload);
} else {
   window.fcSettings = payload;
}
```